# How correctly do I need to press the void pointer?

Tags: c++11

```
void func(const char* str)
{
    void *s = &str;
    std::cout << *(char**)s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello world";
    func(str);

    char *str_1 = "Hello world";
    void *ptr_1 = str;

    std::cout << (char*)ptr_1 << std::endl;
//    std::cout << *(char**)ptr_1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this in C++?

Comment: because i write in c++

Comment: That's not a reason. In practice there's rarely ever a reason to convert to a `void*`, there's nearly always a better solution available

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking at the moment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49544712/edit) your question to make your problem clearer.

Comment: i want know why \*(char\*\*) - correct and (char\*) - no correct, but  when i write  in main function works the opposite - \*(char\*\*)  has error  and (char\*) correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your main is not identical to your function, the function has an extra `&`!

In main, `ptr_1` is a `void*` that points to the static `"Hello world"` array just like `str_1`. So casting to a `char*` is correct.

In `func`, `s` is a `void*` that points to `str`. `s` points to `str` that points to `"Hello world"`. So casting to a `char**` is correct.

Comment: In `func` it might be considered to write it more explicit as `*((char *)(*s))`.  `*s` is the pointer to `str` which is cast to `char *`.

Comment: @milbrandt you can't dereference a `void*` so `*s` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `str` is a pointer to a `char` (C string), `ptr_1`is a pointer to something. So casting `ptr_1`back to a pointer to char `char *` is ok.

in `func` the Argument `str` is already a constant pointer to char `const char *`. The pointer `s` Points to the address of `str`, thus is a pointer to a pointer. Therefore you need to dereference it twice to get the Content of the char array.

The casts used are C-casts. In C++ the cast operators `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` should be prefered:

```
std::cout << *static_cast<char **>(s) << std::endl;
```